# Why is つきあう typically written in kana?

Tags: kana-usage

The kanji version 付き合う contains only elementary characters with their usual readings. Is there a reason why it's still usually written in kana? Is there a difference in nuance when written in kanji?

---

**EDIT** As to why I think that it's typically written in kana, I just observed the following:

- My textbook (イラストでわかる日本語表現) writes it in kana.
- My dictionary (ウィズダム英和・和英辞典) writes it in kana in all example sentences.
- ことえり (Apple's OS X input method) suggests to use kana when I write it.

Of course that's not necessarily representative of contemporary use by native speakers, but it appears that there are some writers who strongly prefer kana.

Comment: Why do you think it is "usually" written in kana?  I see it written with kanji all the time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not. It's often written in kanji and what you are seeing may just be coincidences. Of course it doesn't have to be, and there are times when it's not, but this doesn't mean that it's "typically" written without kanji. I do not believe that there is any difference in nuance between choosing to use kanji and choosing not to. It's possible that using only kana has kind of a 'softer' feel to it, I suppose, but I don't feel that enough of a distinction is made in practical use to say that there's a stark difference between the two.

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D%E5%90%88&ref=sa

Comment: Agreed. I have seen 付き合う more frequently in my experience.